# Why does NaN appear for simple subtraction in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This problem occurred to me when i did this:

```
var y;
var x;

function move(e) {
var x=e.x;
var y=e.y;
}

var a=y-600;
alert(a);
```

When i did this the output was:

```
a=NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

var `a=undefined-600` results in `NaN`

since y is not assigned anything it is `undefined`, and subtracting 600 from it will give you `NaN(not a number)`

It seems you need to a`Asign "y" some value` and you are looking to something with it in `move()` afterwards

**Update from @Jits comment:** moreover , move() function have x,y as its local variables they wont effect the global x,y

Answer (score 1):

The function `move(e)` is never called in your code snippet, so the variable y is not changed from its initial value of `undefined`.

Also, in the scope of your function `move(e)` you declare a new local variable `var y` which overshadows the `var y` in the global scope. That means the local variable `y` is changed and the global variable `y` stays `undefined`.

`undefined - 600` is `NaN`.

[Try this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/u0ephp7j/):

```
var y;
var x;

function move(e) {
    x=e.x;  // manipulate the variables from the surrounding scope,
    y=e.y;  // instead of creating new, local variables
}

move({x:700, y:700}); // actually call the move function

var a=y-600;
alert(a); // should output "100"
```

Comment: It would not be even if it was called, cause `var x, y` is defined in the local scope of the move function. Two temporary variables would be set that would only exist in the function scope.

Comment: @Jite, right, there is a local `y` which shadows the global `y`. Missed that, Updated answer.

Comment: @Jite you have got sharp observation

Answer (score 0):

The function move(e) is irrelevant to this code, as you have not used it anywhere.

As for the reason of NaN, you are substracting 600 from a variable which has been declared but not assigned any value.

Answer (score 0):

simple,your x and y is undefined.

```
var y; //undefined
var x; //undefined
```

just defined x and y and it should work

[FIDDLER DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/7jvcze5j/)

Answer (score 0):

You declare new local variables `x` and `y` in `move`, and you need to initialize an object `e` which contains some values for the properties `x` and `y` which you use to update the outer variables. You should reconsider the logic, but this will work:

```
var y;
var x;

function move(e) {
    x=e.x;
    y=e.y;
}

var e = {x: 1000, y:700};
move(e);

var a = y-600;
console.log(a); // 100
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/voc41e3b/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have created 2 kinds of variables here which is a bit confusing and not a great practice!

1. global variables x & y
2. local variables x & y inside function move(e)

Try to avoid this because as your code grows it becomes tough to manage.
Coming to your problem global variable y is declared and not initialized which means browser engine does not know what to assign to y while parsing and so it will set undefined to this variable and hence the computation on this variable will be NaN(not a number). And function move(e) has to be called somewhere for performing the task you have included within the function.

Answer (score -1):

y is not defined, so y-600 could not be computed.

Comment: But * why* is it not defined?

Comment: To define the value of y, you must do y=something. ie y=0. This is never done in your code. The y in the function is another y, look at variable scope.